# Changing Aero theme to Classic on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, themes

How do I change the Aero theme to Classic in Windows Vista?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the desktop, choose **personalization**
Go to **window colour and appearance**
Click **Open classic appearance properties for more colour options**
Select **Windows Classic**
Click **OK**

Your screen should now flicker for a moment, then drop to windows classic :)